# Haskell -- any easy way to put Data.Dynamic's in a Map?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, dynamictype

I want to map `Data.Dynamic`s to other `Data.Dynamic`s. But, I can't write

```
Map Dynamic Dynamic
```

because there's no `Ord Dynamic`. Is there any solution (like a version of `Dynamic` whose `toDyn` function only accepts `Ord` things, and reifies the typeclass upon boxing?)

<strike>The motivation for this is to have a map from Variables --> Values inside an EDSL compiler. (Clearly the variables can have different types).</strike> **edit**: Sorry, it's not necessary for this problem, I can/should just store the variable name as the key. But, I'm still interested in the question.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hacked a solution if anyone is interested; it's a little tricky / fun :)

Code here: http://pastebin.com/KiJqqmpj .

(I also wrote one for higher-order types, which saves you the need of writing a `Typeable1`, if you always have the same higher-order type function: http://pastebin.com/aqjwFv9p . In some cases, writing `Typeable1` instances can be hard.)

Some values:

```
float1 = mk_ord_dyn (1 :: Float)
float2 = mk_ord_dyn (2 :: Float)
int1 = mk_ord_dyn (1 :: Int)
int2 = mk_ord_dyn (2 :: Int)
```

A little test,

```
*OrdDynamic> int1 == int1
True
*OrdDynamic> int2 == int2
True
*OrdDynamic> int1 < int2
True
*OrdDynamic> int2 < float1
False
*OrdDynamic> float1 < int2
True
*OrdDynamic> int1 == float1
False
```

Comment: Nice trick, but I think you should have explained at a high level what you did: you created a type that works more or less like `Dynamic` does, but whose values encapsulate a comparison function.  This comparison function has to deal with two cases: (a) compare values of the same type, (b) compare values of heterogeneous types.  The first case is handled by just using the common type's `Ord` instance, and the latter is handled by comparing the *types* themselves (so that, e.g., all `Float`s are "before" all `Int`s, as your test shows.)

Comment: @sacundim, sure, I took too much for granted; please feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: Your version of dynamic cannot handle, e.g., functions, which might be important if this is used to implement a DSL.

Comment: @augustss, yes, but functions don't usually have `Ord` implemented on them, so there might be a bigger problems. My EDSL's variables are lowered into C-like data variables, so I'm not personally dealing with that case...

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no way.  By the types involved in the creating `Dynamic` there cannot be.
If you want to be impure you can use `StablePtr`, but that's the best I can think of.

But by changing the type of toDyn to include Ord it can be done.